# Java servlet обновление страницы по нажатию ссылки

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, jstl

Имеется таблица, которая формируется по запросу для пользователя (список курсов, доступных для подписки). Нужно, чтобы по нажатию ссылки на название курса выполнялся метод с SQL запросом, обновлялась страница, курс попадал из одной таблицы в другую (из возможных в активные) и страница обновлялась с новыми данными. Как просписать ссылку в jsp?

Comment: Ссылка прописывается как обычно. А вот все остальное придётся написать отдельно - сервлет и JS код

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось )

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.